# PDO with "WHERE... IN" queries

Tags: php, pdo

I'm reworking some PHP code to use PDO for the database access, but I'm running into a problem with a "WHERE... IN" query.

I'm trying to delete some things from a database, based on which items on a form are checked. The length and content of the list will vary, but for this example, imagine that it's this:

```
$idlist = '260,201,221,216,217,169,210,212,213';
```

Then the query looks like this:

```
$query = "DELETE from `foo` WHERE `id` IN (:idlist)";
$st = $db->prepare($query);
$st->execute(array(':idlist' => $idlist));
```

When I do this, only the first ID is deleted. (I assume it throws out the comma and everything after it.)

I've also tried making `$idlist` an array, but then it doesn't delete anything.

**What's the proper way to use a list of items in a PDO prepared statement?**

Comment: You mustn't add a solution in your question. If you think is a better answer, answer your own question or suggest the edit to the original answer.

Comment: @PhoneixS Fine advice, but I last touched this question in 2010 and haven't really worked with PHP since that year. Feel free to edit if you like.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since you can't mix Values (the Numbers) with control flow logic (the commas) with prepared statements you need one placeholder per Value.

```
$idlist = array('260','201','221','216','217','169','210','212','213');

$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($idlist)-1) . "?";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `foo` WHERE `id` IN ($questionmarks)");
```

and loop to bind the parameters.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I use it like this though: `implode(',',str_split(str_repeat('?',count($idList))));`

Comment: Or: `implode(',', array_fill(0, count($idList), '?'));` (if count > 0 which is mandatory for the answer as well), see [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill), [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/str_repeat)

Comment: @NathanLong solution:
`<input type="checkbox" name="foos[]" value="bar">`
On submission, I get a variable called `$_POST['foos']`, which is an array of the values of all the checked boxes.

Then:

    //As many question marks as array entries; the last one needs no comma
    `$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['foos'])-1) . "?";    
    $query = "DELETE from `employee_customeraccount` WHERE `id` IN ($questionmarks)";
    $st = $db->prepare($query);
    //Each question mark is filled in with the next item in the array
    $st->execute($_POST['foos']);`
It works!

Comment: What @hakre mentioned plus ->execute(array_values($idlist )); to get numeric keys no matter where $idList came from.

Answer (score 9):

This may be helpful too:

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($arr);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -3):

I would make $idlist and array, then simply loop through the array using foreach to delete the specific item.

```
$idlist = array('260','201','221','216','217','169','210','212','213');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `foo` WHERE `id` = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);

foreach ($idlist as $item){
    $id = $item;
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Workable approach, but expensive! Keeping it in one query would be *much* nicer.

Comment: Actually good use of a *prepared* statement. But as mentioned - too expensive.