# Executing array values in a MySQL PDO statement with WHERE and OR

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement

I've been trying to look for a solution where you can fetch database with one prepared statement and execute it with an array value

Typically I do this with my statement:

```
$search = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?");
$search->execute(array($name));
```

But what if i have an array like so:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array 
  ( 
    [name] => Burger Joint 
  ) 
  [1] => Array 
  ( 
    [name] => Burger Joint 
  ) 
  [2] => Array 
  ( 
    [name] => Burgers 
  ) 
  [3] => Array 
  ( 
   [name] => Meats 
  )
)
```

I'd like to somehow go through my database with either of the values in the array `WHERE name=?` in the statement. However, sometimes there's going to be multiple similar names, is there a way to condense the array before hand or what would be the best practice in a situation like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did any of the answers here help you? If not, be so kind to leave a comment :)

Comment: Use `$flat = array_map(function($a) { return $a['name']; }, $array);` to get a flat array, afterwards proceed as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/920523/1266906

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a number of ways, but since you mentioned `OR`, let's use that:

First, your array of possible values. Let's take your array and mold it into an array of unique values:

```
$values_array = array_unique(
    array_map(
        function($element) { 
            return $element['name']; 
        },
        $original_array
    )
);
// $values_array now contains array('Burger Joint', 'Burgers', 'Meats')
```

Now, we build the prepared query by introducing as many placeholders as you have possible values:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table WHERE %s',
    implode(
        ' OR ',
        array_fill(
            'name = ?', 
            count($values_array)
        )
    )
);
// $query now contains 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ? OR name = ? OR name = ?'
```

and execute it:

```
$search = $db->prepare($query);
$search->execute($values_array);
```

Alternatively, you could use `IN` instead, building your query like so:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name in (%s)',
    implode(
        ', ',
        array_fill(
            '?', 
            count($values_array)
        )
    )
);
// $query now contains 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name in (?, ?, ?)'

$search = $db->prepare($query);
$search->execute($values_array);
```

This will have the same effect, and it's slightly more clear what's going on by looking at the code.

Comment: @andrewliu You're right, why _are_ all the answers being downvoted? And they're still at it! But also, did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score -1):

Try `name IN` instead of `name =` .

Comment: I was thinking more about it, and I think I was unclear. I need to use either/or of the values in the array, and not just use ALL values. Would IN work?

Comment: Yes, it should work if you pass the value as an array. In one value's case array with one element.

Comment: The `?` mark is used to avoid SQL injection. I haven't considered it here and so, this is not a complete answer. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2373756/874000). You can prepare your array to avoid SQL injection using str_split, implode or using combination of such functions.(refer the comments of the answer as well)

Answer (score -1):

First, you need IN. `field IN (1,2)` is equal to `field=1 OR field=2`.
Next, you need some sort of helper function, to put all that mess of technical details of creating correct SQL statements **away** from application business code.  To make it in ONE line, not 50.

```
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (?a)",$names);
```

Finally, it seems you're getting your names from another query.
In this case you have to run only single query using JOIN. You may ask another question under `[mysql]` tag providing both your queries.

To get only names into array you have to use another helper function (though you have to create it yourself or get somewhere first):

```
$names = $db->getCol("here goes your query to get names");
```

Comment: I'm getting an array through another query correct, but its not from my database. I'm essentially doing this `$array[] = array("name"=>$names);` But will it matter if i have more than 1 value in array such like this: `$array[] = array("name"=>$names,"id"=>$id,"plural"=>$plural);` How do I only specify names? would it be `$names['name']` at the end of the getAll() function?