# How to get results from database with parameters from array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have table like this:

```
ID | title       | category
-----------------------------
1  | product1    | 0
2  | product2    | 0
3  | product3    | 1
4  | product4    | 1
5  | product5    | 3
```

I have array with ID's, how do I select products with those ID?

I mean something like this but category can be any value from array not only one value like in example.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product where category = '$var'");
```

Comment: Not like that. Use PDO or `mysqli_*`, and escape your variables.

Comment: There is an example of this using PDO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373562/pdo-with-where-in-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = implode(',', $ids); // array(1,2,3,4) =>  '1,2,3,4'
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category IN ('$ids')");
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.

Comment: he asked how to do it in his case I gave him the answer what the problem?

Comment: Your answer will only lead to more problems

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
$arr = array(1,2);
$str = implode(',',$arr);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product where category IN (".$str.") ");
```

**Note that:** Try to avoid the MySQL extenstions, try to use PDO or prepared statements instead.

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.

Comment: @Petah thanks for reminding about deprecation

Answer (score 1):

aside from out of date [mysql_* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)...

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product where category in ('$list_of_ids')");`

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.

Comment: i'm well aware of that and did link the op some other questions to make them aware too. the sql itself is the answer.