# when in clause with mysql pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I would like to run a simple select query using 'where in' clause with mysql pdo.

$start = 12;
$end = 14;

```
for($i=$start; $i<=$end;$i++)
{
$limitin[] = array($qstep,$i);
}
```

The array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 14
        )

)
```

Then

```
$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($limitin)-1) . "?";
```

and the query is

```
$getans = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * 
                              FROM answers
                              WHERE qstep = ? 
                              and ansid in ($questionmarks) ");


$getans->execute($limitin); //$limitin is the array.
```

I am getting a blank resultset and a notice which is 'Notice: Array to string conversion '

Comment: Try this one, I think its already asked [Where in With PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373562/pdo-with-where-in-queries)

Comment: Getting invalid parameter number:mixed as I have qstep as well

Comment: What is it that you're trying to insert, show us an example of what's generating the values for your `IN`

Comment: Plus, add `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything.

Comment: I am not trying to insert.I have a array of values and a single value which I would like to bind with select query.

Comment: Getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function setAttribute()

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did mean the "query/select".

Comment: Still same error I am getting. I think the problem is in binding the values.

Comment: You're using a `foreach`, right? If so, can you show us the rest of the code you're using to generate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$limitin` is a multidimensional array, and is not a valid array to use in `$getans->execute($limitin);`. You need to create a single array. Try something like ->

```
$inarray=array();

foreach($limitin as $key=>$val){
       if($key==0) {$inarray[]=$val[0];} // set the qstep as the 1st array value
       $inarray[] = $val[1]; // add each value
}

$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($limitin)-1) . "?";

$getans = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * 
                              FROM answers
                              WHERE qstep = ? 
                              and ansid in ($questionmarks) ");


$getans->execute($inarray);
```

**edit**

As @Fred-ii- has pointed out, `bindParam()` is another way to do this, for example

```
$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($limitin)-1) . "?";

$getans = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * 
                              FROM answers
                              WHERE qstep = ? 
                              and ansid in ($questionmarks) ");


foreach($limitin as $key=>$val){
       if($key==0) {$getans->bindParam(1,$val[0]);} // set the qstep as the 1st array value
       $getans->bindParam($key+2,$val[1]); // add each value
}

$getans->execute();
```

Comment: So, how does this work without using [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), or am I missing something?

Comment: @Fred-ii- [`PDO::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) has the option of adding the query parameters as an array directly in `execute()`, without the need to `bindParam()` ->  `public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )`::`input_parameters
An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed.`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It only works with PDO, and not mysqli. Your suggestion of `bindParam()` is probably better, as when placing the array in `execute()` -> `All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR`. But since mysql loosely compares values, `('12','13','14')` will be treated like `(12,13,14)` when returning rows.

Comment: Since the OP's using integers, then that would work. Will wait to get a response from the OP, see what gives; *cheers*

Comment: Another questionable piece of code OP's using is `WHERE qstep = ?` I don't know how OP plans on binding that. OP's question is unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- true, that is why when I saw that the OP was placing `$qstep` as the 1st value of each `$limitin[]`, I did `if($key==0) {$inarray[]=$val[0];}` in the original example, and `if($key==0) {$getans->bindParam(1,$val[0]);}` in my edited example.

Comment: Hi guys first of all sorry for replying late as it was around 5 in the morning when I posted this question.Sean thank you very much for your brilliant idea and moreover a fantastic explanation of how array things work with execute function and yes thanks once again for your help.Selected :)

Comment: Hi Fred sorry for replying late.Actually in select query the qstep will be just a parameter with a integer value so it doesn't matter (or matter?) if I put the qstep at the beginning of where clause or at the end.Please correct me if I am wrong. And yes thanks very much for your support around half 4 in the morning when the night appeared to be more darker than usual.