# DELETE FROM table WHERE IN() prepared statement deletes only the first value of array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

through ajax you get an array for $_POST.

This is my code.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$deletethesestring = '';
foreach ($_POST as $v)
{

    $deletethesestring .= $v.',';

}

$deletethesestring  = rtrim($deletethesestring ,',');

echo $deletethesestring;



$deleteprizesqry = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM tbname where tbname_id IN(:deletethesestring);');
$deleteprizesqry  -> bindParam(':deletethesestring', $deletethesestring);

$deleteprizesqry->execute();
?>
```

if my array is for example [9,7,3,4,8,5]
my code only deletes 9. and the rest still stay. I want it to delete every row whose id belongs in the array. how do i do this?

Comment: what is the output of echo $deletethesestring; ?

Comment: @VipinJain 9,7,3,4,8,5 after the rtrim() line.

Comment: Is `tbname_id` a numerical column or a `varchar` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen int(10)

It deletes the first value in the array though. which would be 9 in my example while the other rows stay(not deleted).

Comment: This is not the answer. I have a suggestion for your code. Dont complicate the code. Just use implode to split the array to coma separated string. `implode(',', $_POST)`. In this case you dont need to use any other functions like trim.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: You're not putting quotes around the list of numbers, which appears to be correct.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373562/pdo-with-where-in-queries

Comment: You can solve this by make small changes, check posted answer.

Comment: Thanks i'll try your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$deletethesestring = '';
foreach ($_POST as $v)
{

    $deletethesestring .= $v.',';

}

$deleteIds  = rtrim($deletethesestring ,',');

$deletethesestring = join(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST), '?'));

$delQry = "DELETE FROM tbname where tbname_id IN($deletethesestring)";
$deleteprizesqry = $pdo->prepare($delQry);
$deleteprizesqry->execute($_POST);
```

Hope this help you well!

Comment: thanks. I just added +1 to count($deletethesestring)

then used

$_POST in execute instead of $deleteIds.

Comment: actually.. count($deletethesestring) should be count($_POST) afterall.

Comment: and we don't need the foreach part anymore :D