# How to use PDO prepared statements with IN clause?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, in-clause

I stored some data in a field inside MySQL in this format: *1,5,9,4*
I named this field *related*. Now I want to use this field inside an **IN clause** with **PDO**. I stored that field contents in `$related` variabe. This is my next codes:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,title,pic1 FROM tbl_products WHERE id IN (?) LIMIT 4";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($related));
echo $q->rowCount();
```

But after executing this code, I can fetch only one record whereas I have to fetch 4 records (1,5,9,4). What did I do wrong?

Comment: The common path is to use an extra table for the relationship. This is bad database design.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I know that, this is just a sample for my question.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373562/pdo-with-where-in-queries

Answer (score 1):

using named place holders

```
$values = array(":val1"=>"value1", ":val2"=>"value2", ":val2"=>"value3");
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE `column` in(:'.implode(', :',array_keys($values)).')';
```

using ??

```
$values = array("value1", "value2", "value3");
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE `column` in('.trim(str_repeat(', ?', count($values)), ', ').')';
```

Comment: It might have been downvoted because `table` is a reserved keyword, or a duplicate question, or [an answer copied in two places on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70082897/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

You need as many `?` placeholders as your "IN" values.

So:

```
$related = array(1,2,3); // your "IN" values

$sql = "SELECT id,title,pic1 FROM tbl_products WHERE id IN (";

$questionmarks = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($related);$i++)
{
    $questionmarks .= "?,";
}

$sql .= trim($questionmarks,",");
$sql .= ") LIMIT 3;";

// echo $sql; // outputs: SELECT id,title,pic1 FROM tbl_products WHERE id IN (?,?,?) LIMIT 3;

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($related); // edited this line no need to array($related), since $related is already an array
echo $q->rowCount();
```

https://3v4l.org/No4h1

(also if you want 4 records returned get rid of the `LIMIT 3`)

More elegantly you can use [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to append your placeholders like this:

```
$related = array(1,2,3); // your "IN" values

$sql = "SELECT id,title,pic1 FROM tbl_products WHERE id IN (";
$sql .= trim(str_repeat("?,",count($related)),",");
$sql .= ") LIMIT 3;";

// echo $sql; // outputs: SELECT id,title,pic1 FROM tbl_products WHERE id IN (?,?,?) LIMIT 3;

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($related); // edited this line no need to array($related), since $related is already an array
echo $q->rowCount();
```

https://3v4l.org/qot2k

Also, by reading again your question i can *guess* that your `$related` variable is just a `string` with value comma-separated numbers like `1,40,6,99`. If that's the case you need to make it an `array`. do: `$related = explode($related,",");` to make it an array of numbers. Then in your `execute` method pass `$related` as-is.