# how to implement mysql IN(,) function inside PHP for flutter use

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I'm trying to use the mysql IN(,) function for flutter use, to retrieve two values from a single column

"SELECT * from `TABLE`  WHERE COLUMN
IN (VAL1,VAL2) "<= Now this works fine in thunder client, I just want to implement it for flutter use, I tried:

"SELECT * from `TABLE`  WHERE COLUMN
IN (?,?) " <= but I didn't know how to assign it to the PHP variables.

please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PDO prepared statements with IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827340/how-to-use-pdo-prepared-statements-with-in-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to concat PHP variable to a string, try this:

```
"SELECT * from TABLE WHERE COLUMN IN ('".$VAL1."','".$VAL2."') ";
```

Comment: Imploding values would be more appropriate instead of writing them by hand

Comment: yes, but how can you do it if the column datatype is string? You need a wrap the value in qoutes.

Comment: `'"' . implode('",', $values) . '"'` - that's how

Comment: no its not. run it then show your result.

Comment: https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5eLlUilLzClNLVawVYg21FEw0lEwjrUGiacmZ-QrqCupK-gpZOYW5OSnpGqoK-koqesoQHVoAmWA8tYA&v=8.2.5