# Constructing mysql select from $_POST array

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the $_POST array from my form.

```
Array ( [prescribedid] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 9 [4] => 13 )
```

I want to create a select for any of items in the Array. I have written this, which produces the proper SELECT, but the if() to eliminate a trailing OR makes it clunky.

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM prescribed WHERE ";

for($i=0; $i<count($_POST["prescribedid"]); $i++) {
    $query .= "prescribedid={$_POST['prescribedid'][$i]} ";
        if($i < (count($_POST["prescribedid"])-1)) {
        $query .= "OR ";
        }
}
```

It produces this:

```
SELECT * FROM prescribed WHERE prescribedid=1 OR prescribedid=2 OR prescribedid=3 OR prescribedid=9 OR prescribedid=13
```

Is there another way to group the SELECTS or write the FOR() to make it cleaner, i.e. without the last IF().

Comment: `Tip:` You can use `IN` in order to avoid multiple `OR` clauses. `...WHERE prescribedid IN (1,2,3,9,13)....`

Comment: `Tip:` You need to use PDO or vaidate input. This code can be used for SQL injection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$values=implode(",",$_POST["prescribedid"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM prescribed WHERE  prescribedid IN ($values)";
```

**[Sanitization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373562/pdo-with-where-in-queries)** is on you :)

Answer (score 4):

Use MySQL IN clause

```
$ids = implode(",",$_POST["prescribedid"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM prescribed WHERE  prescribedid IN ($ids)";
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi You can Use `In` `condition`. use `imploade` function to find comma seoarated values

```
$data = array('prescribedid'=>array(1,2,3,9,14));
$query = 'SELECT * FROM prescribed WHERE  prescribedid IN (';
$query .= implode(',',$data['prescribedid']).')';
echo $query ;
```

Output

```
SELECT * FROM prescribed WHERE prescribedid IN (1,2,3,9,14)
```

Comment: You don't need the string concatenation (and it *may* cause some confusion, especially in this layout.)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use IN clause here.

Refer to [MySQL IN clause](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM prescribed WHERE  prescribedid IN ".implode(',', $_POST["prescribedid"]);
```