# sql pdo php where in variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'd like to select some data from my database using variables.

Here is a short version of my code:

```
// $a is either null or something like [1, 2]
if ($a) {
    $debug = implode(',', $a);
} else {
    $debug = [0-9];
}

$sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE id IN ($debug)"
```

How can I achieve that I get only user 1 and 2 (= value in `$a`) if `$a` is set and all user if `$a` is not set?

Comment: Have you tried `isset($a)` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373562/pdo-with-where-in-queries for how to do this with prepared query instead of substituting strings.

Answer (score 1):

**First**:
be aware when you directly inject string inside queries, because you can be target of a SQL Injection

**Second**:
change directly the query might be the easiest solution

```
// $a is either null or something like [1, 2]
$sql = "SELECT id FROM user";
if ($a) {
    $debug = implode(',', $a);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE id IN ($debug)";
}
```

Comment: ` target of a SQL Injection` does this not need input from a user? If `$debug` is only set with known values (not from `$_POST`, or so) then this should not be a problem.

Comment: Does something like `SELECT id FROM user WHERE id IN (any number)` exist?

Comment: @Luuk infact in my code i've injected directly the string since idk where that array comes from, but i'm warning him of that possibility

Comment: @Luuk the values are from $_GET but I check if the array just contains numbers :).

Comment: @user13977445 i'm unable to find any way to achieve what you are asking using numbers, or if you really really need this kind of things, you can use something like `where ... id IN (select id from user)` and so injecting `select id from user` as string, but i mean, it's not that great as a suggestion ahah

Comment: @Berto99 hmm, I think I have no other option then selecting the id. is this a security risk? Can I store the select statement in a variable and then use this varible like ... in ($var)? I don't get it to work :/

Comment: @Berto99 otherwise I can select all ids in a different statement an store them in a variable? Is this a "better" option?

Comment: @user13977445 sorry for the question but, why the solution shown in the answer does not fit your requirements?

Comment: @Berto99 just because the sql statement is very very long (more than 10 joins, multiple where and grouping). If there is another option I'd be glad :)!

Comment: @user13977445 can you please post the real cases? so that i can maybe manipulate the string in a better way

Comment: @Berto99 I figured out a solution yesterday: I store part of the sql query (tbl_user in (1,2)) or just the value true in a variable so I can use it in the actual sql statment like SELECT id FROM user where [...] and $var. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can set flag on $a to check if its null
$debug must contain a comma separated string with ids i.e '2,32,12,54,56,76'

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM user ";
if(!empty($a)){
$debug = implode(',', $a); //here you must get string like '1,2,3,4,5'
$sql .= " WHERE id IN ($debug)";
}

//here if $a is empty you have all rows and if $a have values you get selected rows

//final query will be
// if a is empty 'SELECT id FROM user '
// else 'SELECT id FROM user WHERE id IN (1,2,3)' // where 1,2,3 got from $debug
```